# ubuntu user is missing when creating an image with diskimage-builder (xenial cloud image as base)

Tags: ssh, cloud, openstack, ubuntu-16.04, diskimage

I have tried to create a ubuntu new image using diskimage-builder v1.19.0 but I fail to log into this image using ssh with keys.
This only happens when I take the base image from: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/

> ssh 10.68.32.164 debug1: Connecting to 10.68.32.164 [10.68.32.164]
>   port 22. debug1: Connection established. debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/ubuntu/.ssh/quantum.pem type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/ubuntu/.ssh/quantum.pem-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling
>   compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string
>   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 debug1: Remote protocol
>   version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat
>   0x04000000 debug1: Authenticating to 10.68.32.164:22 as 'ubuntu'
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent Connection reset by 10.68.32.164 port 22

I have tried the same procedure with base images from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vivid/ and this works fine.

When I mount the resulting xenial image and look in the home directory I notice that there is no ubuntu user, only a devuser.
The keys I supplied when instantiating the image is stored under devuser.

> ls -l total 16 drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 Sep 16 09:22 ./
>   drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root   4096 Sep 16 09:22 ../ drwxr-xr-x  3   1001
>   1001 4096 Sep 16 09:22 devuser/

Creating an instance using heat templates with the original ubuntu image is also working fine. No problems to login with ssh.

I only have DIB_RELEASE set to xenial and DIB_CLOUD_INIT_DATASOURCES set.
DIB_DEV_USER_USERNAME is unset.

What do I need to do to have the ubuntu user created?

Br Mat

Answer (score 0):

Adding the ubuntu user and the .ssh directory including a key solved the issue.